# Reading multiple files and check for EOF

Tags: c++, eof

I am working on a project in C++. I have to read different files. And somehow, only the first file works and others don't. My code is below

```
void scanner::readfile(string input)
{
 infile.open(input);
    while (!infile.eof())
     { .......
       ......
     }
 }
```

After I read my first file,It works perfectly fine. So when I try to read the second file, it won't even go into the while loop. So I use infile.peek(), it returns -1 for every file after first file. I assume that maybe infile is stuck at EOF from last file.  Is there anywhere I can fix the problem?

Comment: You appear to be reusing the same `std::ifstream` object. You have to `close()` it, before you can `open()` it again, to read another file. Even better, the `std::ifstream infile` object should simply be an object local to this function, to avoid this issue in the first place.

Comment: What is infile?  Is it declared at function scope?  It should be.  If not,that's where your problem comes from.

Comment: I declared infile as ifstream infile as data member in my class. And readfile is a function of that class

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. It worked after I put infile.close() at the end. However, I don't quite understand why I have to put close at the end. Why can't I just keep reading files after files?

Comment: Because it is an error to open a `std::ifstream` when it is already open. The file object must be closed before it can be opened again. Before you can replace a tire on your car you must remove the old tire, first.